# SQL not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the table I created and the `insert` statement that I have.

What is wrong with this?

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_SA
(FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
AIRCRAFT_ID CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
TRANSFER_FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP,
ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP,
DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(15),
TRANSFER_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(15),
ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(15),
DURATION CHAR(5));

INSERT INTO FLIGHT_SA
VALUES
('MS986','B773','MS798','2016-06-05 10:45:01','2016-06-05 12:45:01',
 'Baltimore,MD (BWI)','Philadephia,PA (PHL)','Miami,FL (MIA)','5 HOURS');
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting?

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Note that Philadelphia has two l's in it, and is too long to fit in the airport code, so its value will be truncated, at best.  Baltimore suffers the same truncation fate.  Even the duration doesn't fit in the space allocated.  For airports, you'd normally store the IATA 3-letter code in the tables and have a separate table of Airports with which to join — foreign keys, referential integrity, normalization: all the good stuff.

Comment: As Jonathan mentioned, the three letter airport code (e.g. YYZ)  could be stored as a separate column. That makes data validation and integrity checks much easier.  You can concatenate (combine) character columns together when you pull them out of the database for display, or do the concatenation in your client.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried it on sql server, `TIMESTAMP` format must be unique in a table. I didn't know you were on Oracle. This works on SQL server :

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_SA
(FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
AIRCRAFT_ID CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
TRANSFER_FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
TRANSFER_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
DURATION CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO FLIGHT_SA
VALUES
('MS986','B773','MS798','2016-06-05 10:45:01','2016-06-05 12:45:01','Baltimore,MD (BWI)','Philadephia,PA (PHL)','Miami,FL (MIA)','5 HOURS');
```

And for Oracle, you need the `To_date` function (http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_date.php) :

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT_SA
(FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
AIRCRAFT_ID CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
TRANSFER_FLIGHT_NUMBER CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME DATETIME,
DEPARTURE_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
TRANSFER_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
ARRIVAL_AIRPORT_CODE CHAR(30),
DURATION CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO FLIGHT_SA
VALUES
('MS986','B773','MS798',TO_DATE('2016-06-05 10:45:01','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),TO_DATE('2016-06-05 12:45:01','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),'Baltimore,MD (BWI)','Philadephia,PA (PHL)','Miami,FL (MIA)','5 HOURS');
```

This should work. I also corrected the length of you characters variable. Take care, Oracle will truncate your string if you don't give it enough space.

Comment: Sorry i'm using oracle sqlplus

Comment: It's telling me invalid datatype line 5

Comment: Try then just date, i'm not sure as I use sql server

Comment: ok I just figurd it out, you need the to date function in oracle. I correct my answer.

Comment: where does the to_date function go

Comment: Look at my answer that I just edited, it is in the insert directly, I created a statement for oracle

Comment: Could you validate my answer then ? Thanks !